# MYSQL query to join four tables into one table

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

Following is the schema of my database. I have been working on a query, but not able to get correct results.

```
TABLE: CUSTOMERINFORMATION  
FIELDS: CUSTID, ACTOPTIONID,VAT,MINIMUMDOCT 

TABLE: ONLINEORDERS 
FIELDS: CUSTID, TOTALQUANTITY 

TABLE: OFFLINEORDERS
FIELDS: CUSTID, TOTALQUANTITY 

TABLE: ACTOPTS 
FIELDS: ACTOPTIONID,ACTNAME
```

OUTPUT LIKE THIS:
TEMPORARY TABLE: CUSTID, ACTOPTIONID, TOTALONLINEQ,TOTALOFFLINEQ,ACTNAME

I need to combine all the above tables and mentioned fields into ONE TABLE.
We also need to make sure that NULL rows are returned; meaning UNION ALL for all the above.

This is to create a data export utility where all the above would be exported out into another table. but we need to make sure no records are excluded even if there are no matching records in tables against others.

### Edited

Following is my query:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.*
  FROM (SELECT ao.actname,
               ci.custid,
               ci.actoptionid,
               ci.minimumdoct,
               ci.vat
          FROM customerinformation ci, actoptions ao
         WHERE ci.actoptionid = ao.actoptionid) table1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT custid, totalquantity, FROM onlineorders) table2
          ON table1.custid = table2.custid
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT custid FROM offlineorders) table3
          ON table2.custid = table3.custid
```

However, the above does not return rows from the tables on the RIGHT. I want to return ROWS from the tables to the right and for that I THINK I NEED TO USE UNION ALL ON ALL OF THESE. HOW DO I DO THAT?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you heard about `FULL OUTER JOIN` and how to emulate it in MySQL using a combination of `LEFT JOIN`s, `RIGHT JOIN`s and `UNION`?

Comment: Yeah, i checked on this site and learned about LEFT, RIGHT and then a UNION ALL to emulate FULL OUTER JOIN. Let me edit the question and share my query as well. I should have shared it earlier.

Comment: ok i have edited the question to include my current query. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: What you meant saying "tables on the RIGHT"? The easiest way to understand what you need, it is to provide sample data and result depended on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CI.CUSTID, CI.ACTOPTIONID, O.TOTALQUANTITY TOTALONLINEQ, 
       O1.TOTALQUANTITY TOTALOFFLINEQ, A.ACTNAME, 
       (O.TOTALQUANTITY + O1.TOTALQUANTITY) TotalQuantity  
FROM CUSTOMERINFORMATION CI 
INNER JOIN ACTOPTS A ON CI.ACTOPTIONID = A.ACTOPTIONID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT CUSTID, TOTALQUANTITY FROM ONLINEORDERS ORDER BY DATE DESC) ASs A GROUP BY CUSTID) O ON CI.CUSTID = O.CUSTID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT CUSTID, TOTALQUANTITY FROM OFFLINEORDERS ORDER BY DATE DESC) ASs A GROUP BY CUSTID) O1 ON CI.CUSTID = O1.CUSTID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would the above not exclude the NON-MATCHING ROWS from the TABLE TO THE RIGHT???? I do not want to exclude them for now.

Comment: Your master table is customers and all other tables like online orders and offline orders have information which exists in customer table

Comment: Do you want records customer wise or order wise? I think that online order and offline order table contains multiple entry for 1 customer. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: yes, multiple entries for each order in online and offline orders. I want records returned against each custid

I have also edited the question to show my CURRENT QUERY

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if it works or not. As per my understanding you want output in this format

Comment: thanks i would check and let you know. and just to be complete in my question, what i intend to do is to get all this information into another table. Total quantity field has more than 1 per customer, but we only want the last one which we can get sorted on date column. So, the output would be total quantity from online and offline orders (last entered data), along with other information as 1 ROW for EACH CUSTOMER.

Then, we export that data to another table or excel for analysis.

Comment: With your query entered above, it is excluding some rows. please check my query above in my question.

What I did was that I used the query in my question UNION QUERY REPEATED WITH RIGHT JOIN (instead of left). So,

LEFT JOIN QUERY UNION RIGHT JOIN QUERY  
All Columns same in both queries except changing of LEFT TO RIGHT. I want to do the same in one query.

Comment: Thanks man. I think this would do the trick. But i would need to wait until EOD tomorrow to verify this with my partner. I would verify and confirm my reply here by tomorrow. But for now I think this should do the trick. 
Also,  the sum doesnt work. query works without it but when i use sum mysql syntax err.THANKS AGAIN

BTW, can you tell me what steps to take to construct these complex queries in the future? I cant seem to get the hang of concepts no matter how hard i try to write query after query... how do you actually break the query down into parts and then construct it step by step??????

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have remove the SUM Function. One more thing I want to know is you have one customer wirh CUSTID = 1 and in Onlineorders you have 3 entries as 10, 20, 30 in sequence so my last entry is 30 and same as in Oflineorders with data as 50,60,70 so latest entry is 70. So you want data as CusetId = 1 and Orders = (30+70) = 100 or Custid = 1, Online order = 30, offlineorder=70. Let me know what is correct?

Comment: Hey, yes data should be in both formats as follows:
CUSTID=1, ONLINE_ORDER=30, OFFLINE_ORDER=70, TOTAL_ORDER=100
I figured out the sum and replaced it with a PLUS SIGN. So, the above data format would work with the query you have given right?

Comment: can you also tell me some tips and strategies to create such complex queries (complex in my review, they seem very simple for you). I just cant get the hang of sql queries.

Comment: Check this link this will help you http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

Comment: ok i would accept it and create another question for my question. but please make sure to answer that one :)

BUT BEFORE I CLOSE THIS, PLEASE HOW TO CHANGE THE ABOVE QUERY TO USE FULL OUTER JOIN INSTEAD OF LEFT JOIN? LEFT JOIN WOULD REMOVE ROWS FROM THE TABLE TO THE RIGHT

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`CUSTOMERINFORMATION`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
`ONLINEORDERS` ON (`CUSTID`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
`OFFLINEORDERS` ON (`CUSTID`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
`OFFLINEORDERS` ON (`ACTOPTS`)
```

Comment: ok i have edited the question to include my current query. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```
    SELECT CI.CUSTID,
          CI.VAT,
          CI.MINIMUMDOCT,
          ONL.TOTALQUANTITY as ONLINE_TOTALQUANTITY,
          OFF.TOTALQUANTITY as OFFLINE_TOTALQUANTITY,
          A.ACTNAME 
   FROM CUSTOMERINFORMATION CI
        LEFT JOIN ACTOPTS A
          ON CI.ACTOPTIONID = A.ACTOPTIONID
        LEFT JOIN ONLINEORDERS ONL
          ON CI.CUSTID = ONL.CUSTID
        LEFT JOIN OFFLINEORDERS OFF
          ON CI.CUSTID = OFF.CUSTID
```

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. 
I am sorry but I am a newbie with SQL. Wouldn't I need to use joins? My earlier query uses LEFT JOIN but with that i got missing rows from the table to the right. Then I used RIGHT JOIN, and vice versa. Then, I decided to do a UNION ALL on both but got syntax errors and that is when i posted the question.

Comment: Can you provide a short test data and result on it which you want to achieve?

Comment: BTW, as an aside related to the topic at hand, do the following figures tell me something about the data? I am sorry but i am learning SQL 

total records in ONLINEORDER: 10,000
total records in OFFLINEORDER: 10,000

When I use LEFT JOIN i get resultset with 10472 records
when i use RIGHT JOIN i get resultset with 10003 records
with inner join i get 903 records

Do the following tell me something about the data? as in missing records, and data integrity?

Thanks

Comment: I tried the query you gave. It is rendering row wise. For example first iam getting all rows from CUSTOMERINFORMATION, then from ONLINEORDER, etc.

MY output should be like this
CUSTID,ACTOPTIONID,TOTALONLINEQUANTITY,TOTALOFFLINEQUANTITY,ACTNAME

when there are no matching rows against some field, those fields should be blank and show as NULL.

Comment: ok i have edited the question to include my current query. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using a `FULL JOIN` if you want matches on either the `LEFT` OR `RIGHT` tables

- [W3SCHOOLS - SQL FULL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)

As a side note, the `UNION` command joins two `SELECT` statements, which you don't have in the current form. If you want to use `UNION` then you should reorder your statements into `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...`